# Finding maximum number of register counts from instruction size, op-code size, and number of operands

Tags: computer-science, cpu-architecture, cpu-registers, instruction-set

I've been trying to wrap my head around how to achieve the answer. I'd like to say I did my own research but either I'm not searching the right questions or I'm blind. Can someone please explain the logic behind finding the answer? I am at a loss.

**Enter the register counts:**

**16 bit instruction, 5-bit opcode, maximum register count with 2 operands**

**16 bit instruction, 8-bit opcode, maximum register count with 2 operands**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just arithmetic.  16 bits total, 5 are used for the opcode, leaving 11.  Dividing 11 by two shows that if you need two operands, each one can have at most 5 bits to represent it, and you'll have 1 bit left over for something else.  With 5 bits you can address 2^5=32 registers.

Now you do the other one.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I really appreciate it. As for the question,

Would it be 2^4 = 16 registers since we will have 8 bits left over for two operands (4 each) after the opcode? 

Using a more complicated example, "32 bit instruction, 10-bit opcode, maximum register count with 3 operands". Would the arithmetic be as follows: 32 bits - 10 bit opcode = 22 bits. 22bits/3 operands = each operand can have 7 bits with 1 left over. Therefore, we can address 2^7 = 128 registers.

Comment: @MarkKobain: Right, you've got the idea.  Really just counting.